# Displaying PDF in Browser - Showing Thumbnails ("Pages") by Default

Tags: pdf, adobe, itext, acrobat

I'm currently using ITextSharp to write a PDF to a web browser, but I cannot figure out how to, by default, show the thumbnails on the left side. If I click the "Pages" button they appear correctly, but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it by default.

I thought this might be a setting within adobe's browser PDF viewer, but I can't find that either.

Can this be programmatically done or is there a setting that is eluding me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anybody was curious, this is the solution I came up with (for ITextSharp).

```
PdfWriter pdfWriter = ...
pdfWriter.ViewerPreferences = PdfWriter.PageModeUseThumbs;
```